# Comparación con input para ciclo while en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una pequeña duda sobre un input para preguntar si se desea continuar la iteración de este. (No sabría como nombrar a este método o expresión, intenté buscar información pero no sé cómo se le conoce o cómo buscar algo sobre esto por su nombre.)

Pondré este código de ejemplo:

```
opc = True
while opc:
    print("Ejemplo")
    opc = input("Deseas continuar el ciclo? (S/N): ") == "S"
```

No sé cómo se le conoce a esta última parte que aparece en la línea del input donde si la opción es igual a S (== "S") devuelve un valor booleano `True`.

Entonces, en el caso de que yo quisiera que me aceptara también como entrada "s" minúscula y también aceptarlo como `True`, ¿es posible hacerlo en esa misma línea? Algo similar a esto:

```
opc = input("Deseas continuar el ciclo? (S/N): ") == "S" or opc == "s"
```

Puesto que esto no me devuelve error, pero no me devuelve la "s" como verdadero, ¡solo la "S" mayúscula!

¿O no es posible esto de múltiples opciones aceptadas como `True` en ese input y debo hacerlo mediante una condición donde si la respuesta es distinta a "s" o "S" me iguale la variable "opc" a False?

Espero haberme explicado, sé que pude haber sido algo confuso pues como dije no sé como se llame esta comparación después del input (== "x"), es una duda breve y que entiendo existen muchas soluciones distintas para resolverla y trabajar así el while, pero quería saber si justo existe alguna manera de que se validen o comparen múltiples entradas en el mismo input y las devuelva o acepte como `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar una lista con las entradas válidas y utilizar `in`

```
opc = input("Deseas continuar el ciclo? (S/N): ") in ['s', 'S']
```

Otra opción sería evaluar únicamente minúsculas (Si es el mismo caracter yo te recomendaría esta opción), utilzando `lower`.

```
opc = input("Deseas continuar el ciclo? (S/N): ").lower() == 's'
```

Si tuvieras que evaluar más opciones, por ejemplo `s` y `n` podrías combinar los dos métodos.

```
opc = input("Deseas continuar el ciclo? (S/N): ").lower() in ['s', 'n']
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! @HeytalePazguato Fenomenal tu respuesta! :)

Answer (score 1):

La expresión

```
opc = input("Deseas continuar el ciclo? (S/N): ") == "S" or opc == "s"
```

es incorrecta, pues `opc` no está inicializado con la respuesta del usuairo al momento de calcular la expresión de la derecha. Por tanto, cuando preguntas por `opc == "s"`, no estás usando el valor dado por `input`, sino lo que pueda tener (o no tener) de antes.

La solución es ingresar primero, comparar después, como propone HeytalePazguato.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en esa línea solo hago puntualmente el ejemplo de lo que quería hacer en el código que puse antes, donde si inicializo ```opc``` como ```True```  antes del ciclo! :)

Comment: Eso está mal, pues la comparación `opc == "s"` se traduce (reemplazando opc) en `True == "s"`, lo cual es falso. Entonces, si bien la expresión es válida (todos los elementos tienen valor), siempre producirá `False`, pues comparas cosas distintas.

Comment: Correcto, sé que está mal, pero era la "idea" de lo que quería lograr, el poder comparar con múltiples entradas en ese mismo input, que es lo que ya me explicó HeytalePazguato!